# Register User Id and Display name in MFP Push notification

Tags: mobile, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

How to register the device with user id and display name.. In MFP console, its not showing the same..

Is there anyway to add these 2 in "MFPPush.registerDevice" Function ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can see userId in MFP Console whenever user is logged in with `UserLogin` Security Check in the application.

   Refer User Authentication tutorial to know more about `UserLogin` Security Check in MFP 8.0 : [link](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/user-authentication/)
2. In order to set device display name, You need to use  `setDeviceDisplayName` in your client Application.

   The following are the links to API Documentation for `setDeviceDisplayName` API.

   - Cordova : [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html#setDeviceDisplayName)
   - Android : [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLClient.html#setDeviceDisplayName%28java.lang.String,%20WLRequestListener%29)
   - iOS : [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refobjc-worklight-ios/html/Classes/WLClient.html#//api/name/setDeviceDisplayName:WithCompletionHandler:)
3. You cannot add these parameters using `MFPPush.registerDevice()`. registerDevice() API takes the authentication context (from the security check) and adds the userID and displayName automatically.

Comment: I have added something like the below code

 var options = {};
    options.phoneNumber = "xxxxx";
 WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
        MFPPush.registerDevice(options,successResponse,failureResponse);
    );

Device Successfully registered but in MFP Console "Display Name" and "User Id" is still empty...

But how can i use the phone number as the USER ID ?

Comment: You need to authenticate with the security check with your phone number as user id.